# Drag and Drop Javascript to move chess pieces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'am trying to code a chess game with React/JavaScript.

I already have the board and now I'am using the drag and drop API from JS to move the pieces arround.

However, when I drop the piece in a new square, the piece is placed but no longer stays centered (seems to get some offset) in the square for some reason I can't understand.

PLease check the reproducible example below :

https://codesandbox.io/embed/nostalgic-dream-jd5xib?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: The only droppable squares have numbers in them, so adding the image causes it to appear below the number.  Position relative on the squares with position absolute on the images might do the trick.  It also might obscure the number

Comment: Oh wow, ye, you're right , the text is the cause! So dumb of me, thanks